# SharePoint Session with ASP.net Application

Tags: sharepoint

How to share session variable between one SharePoint site and another asp.net site?

Comment: Please, elaborate. Is it on the same server? A completely different server? The same server, but different virtual host? Maybe the other site is hosted in SharePoint application?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share any data between your asp.net and sharepoint then i would suggest you to keep it in sharepoint property bag. you can access property bag using client object model from your asp.net application

Intro of property bag:
http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/what-is-a-property-bag/
http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/

accessing sharepoint property bag from asp.net app:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Making-use-of-the-Property-Bag-in-the-ECMAScript-Client-Object-Model.aspx